# Set large image in image view using universal image downloader

Tags: android, image, bitmap, image-resizing, universal-image-loader

I am using universal image downloader in my app with following configuration -

```
 ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
       .memoryCacheExtraOptions(1000, 1200)
       .threadPoolSize(4)
       .threadPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY + 2)
       .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
       .memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(1024*1024*5)) // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
       .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
       .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple())
       .build();
       ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Now image i want to display in list can be of any size may be image with high resolution or image with lower resolution but i want to display image with width = device width and hight= fix height say-300dp without blur or stretched image.
Is this possible to create this kind of view.Instagram is using this process.see image below-

[image]

Comment: You might want to create your own imageview and override the onmeasure method. That will be the easiest solution.

Comment: thanks for your answer,i am understand,can you please explain how can i do that.

Comment: is the issue iwth the large memory require for this setting, or are you just asking how to stretch the image to the screen sizes? If the latter then this is not a question related to UID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {
int width = 300;// just setting random value
int height = 300;// pixels
Context context;


public CustomImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.width = getWidthOfScreen();
}

public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    this.width = getWidthOfScreen();
}

public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);//the most important line
}

public int getWidthOfScreen() {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    return display.getWidth();
}
}
```

Here, width is the screen width and height is constant as you wanted.